# If body class equals X then do something?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code running from an external script for an image slider for every page on a site.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#slideshow").show();
  $('#slider1').anythingSlider({
    buildNavigation: false,
    delay: 8000
    })
```

On one of the pages I don't want the image slider to rotate automatically so I need to add an extra variable. I've put a class on the body of the page and want to do something along the lines of...

**If the body has a class of 'partnerCharitiesDetail' then run this script instead of the generic one**

This is what I have tried below (without success). I have 2 questions really,

1) What happens in jQuery when there are 2 identical scripts running (like this example), will it overwrite the older one with the newer one?

2) Where am I going wrong?! Is my approach the best way to do it?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#slideshow").show();
  $('#slider1').anythingSlider({
    buildNavigation: false,
    delay: 8000
  })

  if ($('body.partnerCharitiesDetail').length > 0){
  $('#slider1').anythingSlider({
  buildNavigation: false,
  delay: 8000,
  startStopped: false
 }) 
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I guess my clue was in the bold text "has a class" !

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the `hasClass()` method to check if an element has a certain class.

Also, your code is a little repetitive (and could even cause AnythingSlider to run twice) — I would write it like this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Initialize options first
    var options = {
        buildNavigation: false, 
        delay: 8000
    };

    // Only disable startStopped if the body has this class
    if ($('body').hasClass('partnerCharitiesDetail')) {
        options.startStopped = false;
    }

    // Show the #slideshow element and start the slideshow
    $('#slideshow').show();
    $('#slider1').anythingSlider(options);
});
```

Comment: Great! This works perfectly and is a lot cleaner and makes more sense. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

have you looked at [hasClass](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/)

So you could say

```
if($("body").hasClass("partnerCharitiesDetail"))
{
}
else
{
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if ($('body').hasClass('partnerCharitiesDetail')) {
   ...
```

I would suggest:

```
$("#slideshow").show();
var options = {
    buildNavigation: false,
    delay: 8000
  };

if ($('body').hasClass('partnerCharitiesDetail')) {
    options.startStopped = false;
}
$('#slider1').anythingSlider(options);
```

Answer (score 1):

The behavior depends on how the anythingSlider plugin you're using works. If the plugin accounts for reinitializing a certain element then the second initialization would override the previous, but more likely than not you'd just really mess up your DOM and get double the event listeners etc.

As pointed out, the proper way for checking if something has a class is .hasClass("classname").

```
if($("body").hasClass("partnerCharitiesDetail")) {
}
else {
}
```

Although in this specific case I'd just do

```
$('#slider1').anythingSlider({
     buildNavigation: false,
     delay: 8000,
     startStopped: !($("body").hasClass("partnerCharitiesDetail"))
})
```

and maybe add a comment for future explorers.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
if($("body").isClass(".partnerCharitiesDetail")) {
//code if body has specific class name 
}
else {
//code if body has no specific class name 
}
```

Comment: He's not asking how to use `startStopped` with AnythingSlider. He's asking how to check the body class.

Comment: I think i got ur point. Thank for correcting my mistake friend